# Not able Create react app in vs code - Facing some errors not working

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Aborting installation.
Unexpected error. Please report it as a bug:
Error: spawn UNKNOWN
at ChildProcess.spawn (node:internal/child_process:413:11)
at Object.spawn (node:child_process:757:9)
at spawn (C:\Users\bhumi\AppData\Local\npm-cache_npx\c67e74de0542c87c\node_modules\cross-spawn\index.js:12:24)
at C:\Users\bhumi\AppData\Local\npm-cache_npx\c67e74de0542c87c\node_modules\create-react-app\createReactApp.js:383:19
at new Promise ()
at install (C:\Users\bhumi\AppData\Local\npm-cache_npx\c67e74de0542c87c\node_modules\create-react-app\createReactApp.js:334:10)
at C:\Users\bhumi\AppData\Local\npm-cache_npx\c67e74de0542c87c\node_modules\create-react-app\createReactApp.js:461:16
at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5) {
errno: -4094,
code: 'UNKNOWN',
syscall: 'spawn'
}

I need to clear this above error and run my react app my node version is 17 or 18.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Try to clear the cache using `npm cache clean --force` and `npx clear-npx-cache`. Then try running `npx create-react-app my-app`.

Make sure you have the required node version and npm version

Comment: I have tried the above comment lines but still the app is not created. I have attached the images below

Comment: PS D:\React-assignment final\Tideen Computing - Assignment> npm cache clean --force
npm WARN using --force Recommended protections disabled.

Comment: PS D:\React-assignment final\Tideen Computing - Assignment> npx clear-npx-cache
Need to install the following packages:
  clear-npx-cache@1.0.1
Ok to proceed? (y) npm install clear-npx-cache@1.0.1
npm ERR! canceled

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\bhumi\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2023-03-17T11_02_11_797Z-debug-0.log

Comment: PS D:\React-assignment final\Tideen Computing - Assignment> npx create-react-app my-app
Need to install the following packages:
  create-react-app@5.0.1
    at spawn (C:\Users\bhumi\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_npx\c67e74de0542c87c\node_modules\cross-spawn\index.js:12:24)
    at C:\Users\bhumi\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_npx\c67e74de0542c87c\node_modules\create-react-app\createReactApp.js:383:19         at new Promise (<anonymous>)
    at install (C:\Users\bhumi\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_npx\c67e74de0542c87c\node_modules\create-react-app\createReactApp.js:334:10)

Comment: at C:\Users\bhumi\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_npx\c67e74de0542c87c\node_modules\create-react-app\createReactApp.js:461:16     
    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5) {
  errno: -4094,
  code: 'UNKNOWN',
  syscall: 'spawn'
}

Deleting generated file... package.json
Deleting my-app/ from D:\React-assignment final\Tideen Computing - Assignment
Done.

Comment: PS D:\React-assignment final\Tideen Computing - Assignment> node -v
v18.15.0
PS D:\React-assignment final\Tideen Computing - Assignment> npm -v
9.5.0